# Minecraft Sharing

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and my friends love playing together. I was wondering if there was a way that I could get my friend’s world, but she still has the world. If we can’t both have the same world at the same time, could I possibly get her world and be able to play in it? We both have apple iPads. She has and apple iPhone SE if that matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about multiplayer? If so, both of you connect to the same Wi-Fi network. Have your friend enable Multiplayer and make it available to LAN players. You should be able to join the world after it  loads.

Comment: No, not multiplayer. I’m talking about like for example if I wanted to play in that world, but she didn’t have time to play the world, is there a way that I could get that world?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot. You can only go to her world if she is playing. However, If you play on Realms, you can be on her world without her actually being on it herself. Remember - you must be connected to the internet to play on Realms, and costs money ($0.99/month, if I'm not mistaken). Hope this answers your question. Have a great day Minecrafting!

Comment: Thank you for your help! You too!